# Action of the Galois group on the ideal class group

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Assume that $K/\Bbb Q$ is a cyclic Galois extension, and $\mathfrak{p}$ a prime ideal of $K$ and $\sigma$ an element of the Galois group. What can we say about the classes $[\mathfrak{p}]$ and $[\sigma(\mathfrak{p})]$ in the ideal class group? Let $\left \langle [\mathfrak{p}] \right \rangle$ be the subgroup of the ideal class group generated by $[\mathfrak{p}]$. Do we have that necessarily $[\sigma(\mathfrak{p})] \in \left \langle [\mathfrak{p}] \right \rangle$? I cannot prove this. Also, I do not have any idea how to find a counter example.

Comment: you could have a look at [[math/9812171] Perfect forms and the Vandiver conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9812171)

Comment: Look up genus theory.

Comment: @Niels I can not see how the results in that paper are related to my question. Could you please give an exposition on it?

Comment: @FranzLemmermeyer Could you please introduce a specific book or note or ... to me about this subject? If I am not mistaken, probably genus theory would deal with the cases when the Galois group acts trivially on the ideal class group.

Comment: looks like you got interested: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382930/galois-group-acts-by-the-i-th-power-of-the-teichmuller-character-on-h

Comment: @Niels Much more than interest. My mind is involved with this kind of number theory, around the clock and every moment. Thanks for introducing that article

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is true if $K$ is quadratic, since then $[\sigma(\mathfrak p)] = [\mathfrak p^{-1}]$.

It should be false for every other degree.

The only relation that the Galois action should satisfy is (for cyclic fields of degree $n$) that $ \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} [\sigma^{i}(\mathfrak p)] $ is trivial in the class group, since it's the class of the norm of $\mathfrak p$, which is an ideal of $\mathbb Q$ and thus is principal.

For example, for cubic fields, if this were true then you could never have $p$ congruent to $2$ mod $3$ dividing the order of the class group, as the Galois automorphism of order $3$ would have to act on elements of order $p$ by scalar multiplication by an element of $\mathbb F_p^\times$, and thus would have to be trivial, which is impossible since it would violate the above identity. So it suffices to find a cubic field whose class number is a multiple of $2,$ or $5,$ or ...

Searching quickly on the LMFDB, I found [this counterexample](https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/3.3.26569.1), whose class number is $4$.

Comment: Your statements on quadratic extension and cyclic extensions are very clear. Also, I can check why your counterexample contradicts my claim (I can see it in another way), and I get the answer to my question. But I have another request, could you please tell more on the "Galois automorphism should have to act on elements of order $p$ by scalar multiplication by an element of $\mathbb F_p^\times$"? Can you write down the action of the Galois group?

Comment: @NeoTheComputer No, I just mean that if $\sigma([\mathfrak p]) \in \langle [\mathfrak p \rangle$ then $\sigma([\mathfrak p]) = [\mathfrak p]^a$ for some $a$ mod $p$, because  $ [\mathfrak p]$ has order $p$.

Comment: Thank you for your response.