# Galois group acts by the $i$-th power of the Teichmuller character on $H$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

In the second paragraph of [Soulé - Perfect forms and the Vandiver conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9812171), it is written that:
*For any natural integer $i \le p − 2$, let $C^{(i)}$ be the subgroup of $C$, where the Galois group of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_p)$ over $\Bbb Q$ acts by the $i$-th power of the Teichmuller character.*

I know the definition of the Teichmuller character, $\omega(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty} x^{p^n}$, and I can realize it, but I can not understand the quoted paragraph: *Galois group acts by the $i$-th power of the Teichmuller character on $H$, what does it mean?* I want to realize this.

It is probable that I did not realize the action of the Galois group on the ideal class group, but I think I understand it well enough. So any general explanation on the action of the Galois group on the ideal class group would be welcome too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\Gal{Gal}$So as you defined it, the Teichmüller character operates on $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$, and is basically a homomorphism
$$
\mathbb{Z}_p^\times\rightarrow \mu_{p-1}.
$$
Under the isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times \cong \Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^\infty})/\mathbb{Q})$, it can be thought of as a map $\Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^\infty})/\mathbb{Q})\rightarrow \mu_{p-1}$. This map factors through the quotient
$$
\Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^\infty})/\mathbb{Q})\rightarrow \Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p})/\mathbb{Q})\cong \mu_{p-1}.
$$
This final isomorphism is also sometimes called the Teichmüller character $\omega$. Furthermore, for any $i$, we can talk about the $i$-th power of $\omega$ via $\omega^i(x) \mathrel{:=} \omega(x)^i$, and this is still a well-defined homomorphism.

Now for the paper.

$C$ can be thought of as the Galois group of an abelian extension $K/\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$. So you have an exact sequence of groups
$$
0 \rightarrow C \rightarrow \Gal(K/\mathbb{Q}) \rightarrow \Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)/\mathbb{Q}) \rightarrow 0.
$$
It turns out that in any such exact sequence where the first and third groups are abelian (but not necessarily the second), the third group acts on the first via lifting + conjugation. The action is independent of the lift, proof left to the reader.

So now $C$ is a finite $p$-torsion group, which means it comes with a natural action by $\mu_{p-1}$. Given this action, we can ask for the subgroup of $C$ on which $\Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)/\mathbb{Q})$ acts by $\omega^i$. You can precisely define it as e.g.
$$
\{c \in C \mathrel: \omega^i(x)c = xc \quad \forall x \in \Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)/\mathbb{Q})\}.
$$

Comment: As a meta-comment, it sounds like you're just starting to dip your toes into Iwasawa Theory. The paper you linked is pretty advanced and might be hard to get through. If you're just starting out, I would suggest picking up Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields by Lawrence Washington.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. I can not see this part "*It turns out that in any such exact sequence where the first and third groups are abelian (but not necessarily the second), the third group acts on the first via lifting + conjugation.*", and I stuck there.